# SAS- print Single Quotes without spaces

Tags: sas

How can I remove the space at the end of the output? I am getting a space at the end within quotes

```
data _null_;
    files   = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
    f_count = countw(files);
    do i=1 to f_count;
        file = scan(files, i, ',');
        put '''file''';
    end;
run;
output: There is a space at the end

'AAAAAAAAAAAA '
'BBBBBBBBBBBB '
```

Comment: Note the code as posted is not going to write any spaces inside the quotes.  That is because your PUT statement is writing the text `'file'` instead of the value of the variable file.  Either add one more single quote to both sides, `put '''' file '''';` or use double quote characters around the single quotes to quote them. `put "'" file "'";`

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are used LIST MODE style PUT statement. SAS will write a delimiter (space in this case) after each variable written when using LIST MODE style in PUT statements.

You could just use a cursor movement command to back-up one byte so that the closing quote is written over the space.

```
put "'" file +(-1) "'";
```

You could add the quotes to the variable rather than in the PUT statement.  (Then the space will be written after the closing quote.)

```
file = quote(strip(scan(files, i, ',')),"'");
put file ;
```

Or you could use the $VARYING format to write the exact number of bytes that FILE contains.

```
 len = lengthn(file);
 put "'" file $varying200. len "'" ;
```

If you don't mind using double quote characters instead of single quotes you could just use the $QUOTE format.

```
put file :$quote. ;
```

You could also use the DSD option on the FILE statement.  SAS will then automatically add double quotes if they are needed.  They will be needed when the value contains the delimiter character or quote characters themselves.  With the DSD option in effect you can use the ~ modifier in the PUT statement to write quotes around the value even when the value does not require quoting.

```
data _null_;
  file log dsd ;
  files   = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBBBBB';
  f_count = countw(files);
  do i=1 to f_count;
    file = scan(files, i, ',');
    put file ~;
  end;
run;
```